# Installing PHP 5.6 on Xenial (16.04)

Tags: apt, php, drupal, php7

I need to use php5 (5.6) because I'm working on a Drupal 7 project which doesn't support php7. The problem is I recently updated to ubuntu 16.04 Xenial which seems to [no longer support php5](https://www.symfony.fi/entry/php-7-included-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xenial-xerus).

I tried to install it from [this repo](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php), however when It try to install it with apt I always get similar errors.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-cli
Cependant les paquets suivants le remplacent :
  php7.0-cli:i386 php7.0-cli`
```

Which means it's obsolete. How can I install PHP 5.6 on Xenial?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

**Remove all the stock php packages**

List installed php packages with `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "` then remove unneeded packages with `sudo aptitude purge your_packages_here` or if you want to directly remove them all use :

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

**Add the PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

If you get `add-apt-repository: command not found` run the following command first :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

**Install your PHP Version**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

You can install php5.6 modules too for example

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
```

**Verify your version**

If you have installed `php5.6-cli`

```
sudo php -v
```

If you don't have `php5.6-cli`, put this on a .php file

```
<?php 
      //outputs php configuration info
      phpinfo(); 
?>
```

Comment: How to install PEAR? apt shows no php5-pear package, and trying to install php-pear goes and installs php7 again.

Comment: @GrahamWheeler `php-pear` pull just CLI PHP 7.0 (`php7.0-cli`) and that's harmless

Comment: Minor nitpick. You can avoid grep and tr by awk already, e.g. `dpkg -l | awk '/php/ {printf "%s ", $2;}'`

Comment: I got error: 'add-apt-repository: command not found'

Comment: @DotKu you can install that missing piece with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: I cannot install packages. E.g, "sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql" returns "E: Unable to locate package php5.6-mysql"

Comment: Don't forget to `service apache2 restart` if using with Apache.

Comment: Ondřej Surý saving our asses again.

Comment: What do we do if some packages are not found?  I installed php5.6 from the ondrej ppa a week or so ago, today I need the mysql connector, but `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mysql` results in errors like: `Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php5.6-opcache amd64 5.6.28-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
  404  Not Found` for what seems like all deps.  Digging in http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5.6/ I can see opcache for example, but 5.6.29 not 5.6.28 as reported in my error. I have run `apt-get update`, don't know what else to try.

Comment: Oops, never mind - I had not added the mongodb-org repository key, so my `apt-get update` failed on mongodb-org without getting to update ondrej/php/ubuntu.  I thought it was a noisy warning, not a critical failure that halted the update.  Once the mongodb-org key was added, then `apt-get update` completed and my `apt-get install php5.6-mysql` fetched the correct version 5.6.29.  All is well.

Comment: What if I had installed php before though `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`? It seems it doesn't see new installs with `sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl`.

Comment: @oerdnj - that doesn't work, if you install php5.6 and then php-pear, which includes bits of php7.1, when you run pecl you get a load of php errors (invalid for-each arguments). :(

Comment: To reply to my own comment! If you do get loads of errors when running pecl, ensure you've added the php-xml package, e.g. "sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml"

Comment: Do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2` if running apache2

Comment: not working for ubuntu 18.04. showing forbidden.

Answer (score 15):

Run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
```

Check your PHP Version

```
php -v
```

Comment: add `-y` to all commands if you need to run this non-interactive

Comment: This no longer works! The ppa is non-existent!

Answer (score 7):

You can even consider using vagrant (or similar technology) to assist in using both versions at the same time. Vagrant is essentially a VM client designed to help spin VM's up and down quickly and easily with project based configuration; i.e. you can configure a VM specifically for a project and each VM can be different per project if need be.

This means that you can develop a project and test it on your local machine using the same production configuration as the project will be run under. Not only is this great for yourself but also means that a team of developers can always test under the same circumstances as the VM configuration is portable and cross-platform (it's just a text file).

Once vagrant and virtual box are installed, it's as easy as running:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

and once the vm is up and running you can use:

```
vagrant ssh
```

and you can now manually install apache, php and mysql. You can also define a provisioning configuration, so that when you enter:

```
vagrant up
```

the VM builds itself as well as installs all the binaries you need and can even do a git clone of your code, setup networking so you can view the application in your browser, etc.

For more detailed information look here: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/

Comment: It's not really practical. I can just install both `php5.6-fpm` and `php7.0-fpm`, then `fastcgi_pass` to the socket that the desired PHP version is running on (I'm using `nginx`, but I reckon `apache2` must have something similar). It will be much more lightweight.

Comment: I think that `docker` would be more suitable .. It's a good idea, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use XAMPP Linux.You can download any version of xampp linux from the below mentioned official xampp site.

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Enter downloaded file location using terminal.

First give certain permission for the downloaded binary file. (Assume that i downloaded 64 bit binary package.)

```
sudo chmod a+x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.23-0-installer.run
```

Then install the xampp

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.23-0-installer.run
```

If you are download 32 bit binary file do below mentioned like this

```
sudo chmod a+x xampp-linux-5.6.23-0-installer.run 
sudo ./xampp-linux-5.6.23-0-installer.run
```