# Owncloud unclear error

Tags: apache2, 16.04, owncloud-server, php7

I just updated from Ubuntu server 14.10 to 16.04 and also from owncloud 8.2 to onwcloud 9.0 with php 7. When I want to start `owncloud` the following errors occur, and I do not know how to handle them. Can anybody help me?

```
PHP module zip not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

PHP module cURL not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

An unhandled exception has been thrown:
Exception: Environment not properly prepared. in /var/www/owncloud/lib/private/console/application.php:120
Stack trace:

'#0 /var/www/owncloud/console.php(87): OC\Console\Application-loadCommands(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

'#1 /var/www/owncloud/occ(11): require_once('/var/www/ownclo...')
```

Comment: Check using `phpinfo` whether `zip` module is installed or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with PHP5 while Ubuntu 16.04 runs PHP 7. First, check your php version

`php -v`

Next, you need to decide whether to use PHP5 or PHP7.

If you want to use PHP5 [there's a great walkthrough here using Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04). This will also give you access to those same PHP 5 modules.

If you want to use PHP 7 you will need to simply install those PHP 7 modules.

`sudo apt install php7.0-zip php7.0-curl`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing php7.0-zip php7.0-curl or php-zip and php-curl if you are running php 5. I recommend to upgrade to Nextcloud. It is a fully free community fork with a lot of new features including some important security improvements. The zip and curl requirements should be the same.