# Unable to execute the laravel command "laravel new myapp"

Tags: command-line, php, php-cli

Using Ubuntu 16.04. When I execute `laravel new myapp`, I am getting this:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                        
The Zip PHP extension is not installed. Please install it and try again.  

new [--dev] [--5.2] [--] [<name>]
```

To check if I have `php` installed, I executed this command:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps your missing a global install of `laravel` with `composer`:

Now run `composer -version` from a terminal, if you don't see a version printed out then start there.  Install it using this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764782/install-laravel-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/767970). If `composer` is there check if `laravel` is installed globally, run `laravel -version` from a terminal you should see something similar to this:

```
Laravel Installer version 1.3.3
```

Now if that doesn't appear then it's not installed, install using:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Now add composer to your `system PATH` so you can run `laravel` command. Open your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file and this line `export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` to it.

Steps:

1. Open `.bashrc` with `nano`:

   ```
    nano /home/$USER/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add this line `export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`.

   - **UPDATE**: On Ubuntu 18.04 the line should be `export PATH=$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`
3. Source the file with `source /home/$USER/.bashrc`

Now run `laravel -version` from terminal to ensure all went well. At this point you can now run the `laravel` command to create applications.

Source:

[Install laravel 5 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764782/install-laravel-5-on-ubuntu-16-04/767970)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#installing-laravel

#### UPDATE

Since your still seeing that error simply install that extension with:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-zip
```

Now run that `laravel` command again.

Comment: Having done all that ,in my chrome i ran this URL _localhost/laravel52/public/_ and I'm able to see the laravel home page .But still I'm not able to run the laravel new appname command as I am getting the same error .

Comment: Having done all that ,in my chrome i ran this URL **localhost/laravel52/public/** and I'm able to see the laravel home page .

Comment: Did you install all the requirement for laravel to work as suggested on that first link?

Comment: Laravel Installer 1.3.3

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug.

Comment: Ok that means its there I had an error in my syntax, it should have been `laravel --version` so install that extension and give us the good news

Comment: It's showing Laravel 1.3.3

Comment: Now install that extension and run the code to create a new laravel app

Comment: Thank you so much GEORGE!!!! It worked after spending quite some time

Comment: Accept is the tick(✅) mark?

Comment: Yes, and the `^` is to upvote an answer you like

Answer (score 2):

For me it was enough to uninstall and reinstall like this:

```
composer global remove "laravel/installer"
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the missing extension with: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/721688)

Comment: @Stormvirux: Author pasted exception stating his PHP install is missing zip extension. The suggested solution is to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the same problem and a quick solution could be use composer (if you already have it installed). So, check for composer installation:

```
composer -V
```

and use this command to create a laravel project:

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel my-prpject-name --prefer-dist
```