# Install php extensions in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, php

I need to install the following extensions with PHP 5.6 and Ubuntu 16.04, but ubuntu only installs extensions for PHP 7.

Trying to install these extensions produces the following error:
[Installing PHP 5.6 on Xenial (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04/756186)

I need to use the extensions:

```
dom
SimpleXML
xml
```

and the gd library.

Comment: It is very hard to understand your question, I would recommend having somebody you know and who is fluent in English help you with writing your question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ok finding in a lot of blogs and aswer, the obviously answer is add suffix in php, then for install php5.6 or before add this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.0   # for PHP 7.0
sudo apt-get install php5.6   # for PHP 5.6
sudo apt-get install php5.5   # for PHP 5.5
```

later of this you need install extension with the following commands

if you install php 5.6 you need add 5.6 to php, for example

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd php5.6-mysql php5.6-dom php5.6-cli php5.6-json php5.6-common php5.6-mbstring php5.6-opcache php5.6-readline
```

etc . or otherwise if you make php-gd you install gd for php7, and thanks to @elder-geek for add links

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that I am misunderstanding you entirely but if what you are looking for is available for Xenial (16.04) in the PPA you reference, it can be found listed [here.](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php?field.series_filter=xenial)

To enable GD-support configure PHP --with-gd[=DIR] , where DIR is the GD base install directory. To use the recommended bundled version of the GD library (which was first bundled in PHP 4.3.0), use the configure option --with-gd . GD library requires libpng and libjpeg to compile.

There's an alphabetical list of extensions on this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php)

There's also a list of deprecated and experimental extension to be found [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.state.php)

You can also obtain the Current Stable PHP 5.6.23 via [download](http://php.net/downloads.php)

Comment: mm but this extensions of php, how can install in ubuntu and add ppa to ubuntu, thanks

Comment: @JonathanRodriguez     Instructions on how to add the PPA you referenced to Ubuntu can be found at the first link I provided. It seems we aren't understanding exactly what you are looking for. Please [edit] your question and provide further clarity and If I can improve my answer I will. If not perhaps someone else will understand what you want and provide it. It appears that dom at least is a function, not an extension: See: http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php

Comment: gd appears to be a library - http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: xml is also found in the function reference: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Comment: This seems exceedingly broad, you may wish to break this up into 4 questions.  It seems your first question is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported  You may wish to ask seperately how to install/configure gd, xml, dom in PHP 5.6