# How compile/install php-mapscript on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, php, gis

I need to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 but php5 is not officially supported on Ubuntu 16. I install php5.5 by `ondrej` repo https://askubuntu.com/a/756186/483814
but when I try to install `php5-mapscript` on it i get error :

```
root@ubuntu16:~# apt-get install php5-mapscript
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mapscript is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mapscript' has no installation candidate
```

Therefore i try to compile and install php-mapscript from scratch but i don't find any updated and working manual.

So if somebody done it before or have general knowledge about mapserver compilation or if know how to install it from repositories please help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ThomasG77 i did compile and install php5-mapscript of Mapserver7.0.2 
compiled and got loaded successfully:
[image]

The manual is based on mapserver general compile documentations:
http://www.mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#compiling

Here is the manual i follow to compile [Ubuntu 16.04 /PHP 5.5.38-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1]:

1. installing php5.5:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install php5.5
   ```
2. download and extract mapserver source and change directory:

   ```
   wget http://download.osgeo.org/mapserver/mapserver-7.0.2.tar.gz
   tar xvf mapserver-7.0.2.tar.gz
   cd mapserver-7.0.2/
   ```
3. install cmake

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cmake
   ```
4. make `build` directory and change to it [~/mapserver-7.0.2/build]:

   ```
   mkdir build
   cd build
   ```
5. install compile requirement

   ```
   apt-get install libfreetype6-dev 
   apt-get install php5.5-dev
   apt-get install libproj-dev
   apt-get install libfribidi-dev
   apt-get install libharfbuzz-dev
   apt-get install libcairo-dev
   ```
6. config , compile and install

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt \
           -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/91:/usr/local:/opt \
           -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON \
           -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
           -DWITH_CURL=ON \
           -DWITH_SOS=ON \
           -DWITH_PHP=ON \
           -DWITH_FCGI=OFF \
           -DWITH_PYTHON=OFF \
           -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=OFF \
           ../ >../configure.out.txt
   make
   make install
   phpenmod mapscript
   service apache2 restart
   ```