# problem adding ppa in ubuntu server 14.04.05 lts

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to add ppa to ubuntu server 14.04.05 lts and end up with following message
[image: please click here to view the message]

Comment: The `ondrej/php5` PPA was [deprecated and deleted months ago](http://askubuntu.com/posts/109544/revisions). Use the other PPAs as needed.

Answer (score 0):

remove the 5 at the end

if im correct youre trying to add [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) ppa.

do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

and you can install extensions for example: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip`

[source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40779314)
[source 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04)