# Internal Server Error when upgrading to PHP 5.6

Tags: apache2, fastcgi

I already have PHP 5.5.9 With Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1. LTS and just now installed PHP 5.6 from [Installing PHP 5.6 on Xenial (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04)

Right now I've 5.5.9, 5.6 and 7.0 versions.

In the Virtualmin I've set PHP 5.6 version for my website and it's showing Internal Server Error.

Here are the [Virtualmin settings](http://prntscr.com/f8ezng).

Clearly 5.6 version does not have many modules like cgi-fcgi.

In the error log I see these errors:

```
[Tue May 16 13:30:27.477892 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 14640] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 103.47.172.98:59204] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Tue May 16 13:30:27.477948 2017] [core:error] [pid 14640] [client 103.47.172.98:59204] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

What do I need to do to enable PHP with fcgid?

Comment: I' wouldn't mess with default PHP packages and ppa's at all. I've used the referenced ppa _(which is very good)_ to get php7 on trusty _(14.04)_, and it can become a PITA. I'll suggest trying to set up a php5.6 container _(and maybe apache also included using `5.6-apache` tag)_  using `docker` _(or `lcx`)_, which seems a cleaner solution to me. [PHP on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)

Comment: And also you did not specify that you were using Apache.. consider putting that in your question.

Comment: @user5858 Are you using a Lamp server?

Comment: @RayAntebioni yes it is Mysql with Apache 2

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the simplest option to do is to reinstall php and get the newest release as well as possibly uninstalling and reinstalling the Apache2 server as sometimes updating will not work as planned and can mess interconnected software up.

And after looking at it again, it looks like you also had a bad install so again, reinstall the LAMP server altogether (I think that is what you are using).